# Is Uncharted 3 story mode smaller than the previous Uncharted games?

Tags: uncharted-3, uncharted-series

I just finished Uncharted 3, and my guts are telling me that this game has a way smaller story arch than the other games.

My google skills for gaming are not that good, as I'm asking you guys: What is the official story length of the three Uncharted games ?

In time: I played all three games in normal mode.

Comment: How are you defining "official story length"? Length of cutscenes only?

Comment: @Sterno, length of the general gameplay. Cutscenes excluded.

Comment: I don't know how much of the game cutscenes took up, and thus I can't apply the math that would show you game time if you excluded them, but the place to generally look for "How long is <game x>" answers is [HowLongToBeat.Com](http://howlongtobeat.com/gamelist.php?sortby=u&sorthead=). In this case, the average game time for 3 was 8h44m, versus 10h39m for 2 and 8h56m for 1.

Comment: Nice, I did not know that site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Sterno didn't actually post it as an answer, I'll do so for the sake of having the question answered.

In truth, it depends on your skill level and play style. I'm sure as you played more of the series you got better at it so that may have also altered your perception of the experience to some degree, making it seem shorter if not easier as well.

While it's not "official length", as Sterno suggests, [HowLongToBeat.com](http://howlongtobeat.com/gamelist.php?sortby=u&sorthead=) is an excellent reference to find out the average length as experienced by other users. Note that results are dependent on the number of users that contributed their results.

According to the referenced data, ***Uncharted 3*'s main story mode alone was a marginally shorter experience than *Uncharted*, but 2-3 hours shorter than *Uncharted 2* as an average and as a median for most** of the 150-180 players surveyed. It should be noted that the fastest times and completionist times for all 3 games got progressively longer by several minutes so **if you were playing as quickly as you could or completing everything available, it would likely be the longest of the 3 if only by a few minutes to an hour.**